# RXJS - Processing an array of items

Tags: rxjs

So I'm working with a data processing pipeline. With a single item, it works well. It starts to break down when I try to do the same process with an array of items. Here's what I have so far that works with a single item.

```
this.thingService.getThingById(thing.id)
    .flatMap(i => {
      return this.createThingVM(i)
    })
    .flatMap(j => {
      return this.getMoreInfoAboutTheThing(j)
    })
    .flatMap(z => {
      return this.getMoreThingData(z)
    })
    .flatMap(y => {
      return this.finalThingProcessing(y)
    })
    .subscribe(x => console.log('Single thing' + JSON.stringify(x)));
}
```

Each step takes a `Thing and returns an Observable<Thing>`.

Processing the thing requires a particular order. When I try to do concatmap first, I get the error `You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do your processing steps truly make streams of values, or are they just single values wrapped in `Observable`? It's hard to imagine expanding and flattening your stream over and over gives meaningful output, and that might be why processing more than one item gives you trouble.

Comment: hard to help you if you don't tell us what all those functions are returning or what your "broken" code looks like

Comment: To clarify, they are values wrapped into an Observable<Thing>.

Comment: can you provide some more stack trace to understand where the error generates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Some of the methods were incorrect. I needed to return an Observable in all cases, and occasionally those HTTP requests failed.